# Hadoop S3 List Bucket Contents Error

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Not sure what I'm missing here. What's the best way to troubleshoot the below message I get when trying bucket contents from s3 using hadoop 2.7.1. This should be pretty straight forward where I have my core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml files as below and then when I try to run `hadoop fs -ls s3a://<bucket_name>`

hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
    <value>key</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
    <value>secret</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.impl</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Error Message:

```
[root@ip-10-239-197-136 ~]# hadoop fs -ls s3a://<bucket_name>
15/11/29 17:43:11 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
-ls: Fatal internal error
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: ED84F95A33096A67, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Forbidden, S3 Extended Request ID: l4FDE3LnYtOSj0TNUrwqv3yX/3x3RgesasBWDo7WcdrS3rkn/6TCz9+Rt6uylVxGcMaztu7gYH8=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:798)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:421)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3528)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:976)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:956)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1655)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.PathData.expandAsGlob(PathData.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.expandArgument(Command.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.expandArguments(Command.java:218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processRawArguments(Command.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.run(Command.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:340)
```

Comment: http 403: Did you configure the role at the AWS S3 correct (assign sufficient access rights)?

Comment: Looks like you do not have permission to access the contents of that s3 bucket.

Comment: Ever found a fix for this? i have access to the bucket.

Comment: Got the same error. In my case, I can list the contents of the directory, but not a file. Can you list files? – e.g., `hadoop fs -ls s3a://<bucket_name>/file.txt`. I'm using hadoop 2.7.3.